# How to run multiple folder and files using parallel test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I am trying to use the parallel testing gem for my application. So, I want to run some specific folders or files but couldn't able to do. I tried the below things but it didn't work for me

```
rake parallel:spec['spec\/models|controllers']

rake parallel:spec['spec\/?.*(models|controllers|presenters)']

rake parallel:spec['spec\/models spec\/controllers']

rake parallel:spec['spec/models spec/controllers']
```

Comment: Can you add some examples what you do and do not want to match?

Comment: I want to run all the spec files inside models, controllers & presenters folder

Comment: Looking at [this page](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) perhaps try `rake parallel:spec['spec\/(?:models|controllers|presenters)']` [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xqUbEJ/1/)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks only thing I need to add 1 extra slash to make it work after parallel:spec.  rake parallel:spec\ ['spec\/(?:models|controllers|presenters)']

Comment: In your current pattern the forward slash is optional. You might also omit the `.*` if the name of 1 of the group follows directly.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Something like this rake parallel:spec['spec\/?(models|controllers|presenters)']

Comment: My comment about the optional forward slash was about the second pattern of your examples. Does `parallel:spec['spec\/(?:models|controllers|presenters)']` work?

Comment: @Thefourthbird This doesn't work I got an error zsh: no matches found: parallel:spec[spec\/(?:models|controllers|presenters)]

Comment: @Thefourthbird One part of my question is still remaining How to run single or multiple files with parallel test

Answer (score 1):

With inspiration from @Thefourthbird I figured that you only need to separate the file names by pipes, like below.

`rake 'parallel:spec[spec/dates/cook_date_spec.rb|spec/dates/into_production_date_spec.rb]'`

Also, in reference to the error: `zsh: no matches found`. You should wrap everything in quotes similar to my example. I know this is late, but hope it helps someone! It sure took me a while to figure this out :)